# jQuery selector excluding hyperlinks

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Ok, this should be obvious...

I have a div with some text and a link.
I want to change background color for the text, but **NOT** the link.

```
<div id="one">
    Foo bar <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</a> barfoo 
</div>
```

Can't see why this doesn't this work...

```
$("#one:not(a)").css("background-color", "red");
```

or

```
$("#one, #one *:not(a)").css("background-color", "red");
```

and

```
$("#one").find("a").not(this).css("background-color", "red");
```

sets background color to exact opposite of what I want..

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that you have no other element in your div apart the link.

Change your HTML to

```
<div id="one">
    <span>Foo bar </span><a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</a><span> barfoo </span>
</div>
```

Then you can do

```
$("#one :not(a)").css("background-color", "red");
```

(notice the space).

You can do the span insertion automatically :

```
$("#one").html(function(_,h){
  return '<span>'+h.replace(/<a\s+.*?<\/a>/g,function(s){
       return '</span>'+s+'<span>'
  })+'</span>';
});
$("#one :not(a)").css("background-color", "red");
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/UVArurI/1/)

Another solution would be to give the div a red color AND give your link a not transparent color :

```
$("#one").css("background-color", "red");
$("#one a").css("background-color", "white"); // give the color of what's behind the div
```

Comment: Thanks dystroy, that makes sense. However, I'd like to avoid having wrapping text with other elements, if possible. Also, if I can set background for the **whole** div content, or **only** link, it seems logical to be able to do the opposite.

Comment: you need to have an element to which apply your style.

Comment: @user2965139 [But you don't need to insert the span manually](http://jsbin.com/UVArurI/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
$("#one").not("a").css("background-color", "red");
$("a").css("background-color", "white");
```

Because "#one" is the containing div, it is coloring the entire container. Making a selection on the anchor afterwords is the way to retain the color.

Otherwise, you could add something like the following, and then select only the spans:

```
<div id="one">
    <span>Foo bar</span> <a href="http://stackoverflow.com">link</a> <span>barfoo </span>
</div>
```

But that's not exactly semantic. If you're doing something a little more real world,  and a little less barfoo, it might be more practical.